# Move childNodes to other parent affect only half of them

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

I try to move all childNodes from one parent to an other using `NodeList.forEach()` but this works only for the half of them.

```
parent.childNodes.forEach(child => newParent.appendChild(child))
```

you can try yourself here:
https://jsfiddle.net/t4g0vje2/3/

I want to know: Why this is happening? What's your best solution moving all children?

Comment: Related: [Strange behavior when iterating over HTMLCollection from getElementsByClassName](/q/15562484/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that child node is being removed from parent.childNodes each time

```
child => newParent.appendChild(child)
```

is being executed. So you are having a problem since your collection is being modified each time the line above is executed.

```
Array.from(parent.childNodes).forEach(child => newParent.appendChild(child))
```

will do the trick, since you are first creating a new array of 10 elements, and traversing through all of the 10 items

Comment: you can change child.innerText = 'child Node' to child.innerText = 'child Node' + i; to understand what's happening

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this exact same problem with my code as well.  I was doing the following:

```
while (shadowObject.firstChild) {
    parentObject.appendChild(shadowObject.firstChild);
    shadowObject.removeChild(shadowObject.firstChild);
}
```

The way that I fixed it was to remove the removeChild line so it looks like this:

```
while (shadowObject.firstChild) {
    parentObject.appendChild(shadowObject.firstChild);
}
```

which fixed the problem.  Firefox does the same thing.  I found the reason for it at the following links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

The critical point of this article is this:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
> children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference
> to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its
> current position to the new position (there is no requirement to
> remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other
> node).
>
> This means that a node can't be in two points of the document
> simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first
> removed, then appended at the new position.

When you think about it, it makes sense.  This behavior is documented on the w3schools site, but it's easy to overlook.